# jqueryUI Draggable mouse offset

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Trying to code a similar feel to the ios8 Lockscreen, having a dragable item only move on the x axis.

```js
$( "#IDlsDragable" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });
```

```css
.lockscreen {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(89,54,158,1);
  background-image:url('../pics/wall.png');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
}

.lockscreenFace {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:1080px;
  width:1080px;
  height:1920px;
}

.lockscreenSlider {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:-1080px;
  width:200%;
  height:100%;
}

.lockscreenClock {
  position:absolute;
  top:110px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  font-size: 296px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.lockscreenDate {
  position:absolute;
  top:432px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.lockscreenSlideText {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:234px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  background:url('../pics/highlight.png');
  -webkit-animation: slidetounlock 3s infinite linear;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.lockscreenSlideText:before {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size:85px;
  line-height:1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidetounlock {
  0% {
    background-position: -880px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lockscreen">
  <div id="IDlsDragable" class="lockscreenSlider">
    <div class="lockscreenFace">
      <div id="IDlsClock" class="lockscreenClock">
        #TIME#
      </div>
      <div id="IDlsDate" class="lockscreenDate">
        #DATE#
      </div>
      <div class="lockscreenSlideText">
        slide to unlock
      </div>
      <div class="cameraGrabby">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I begin to drag it to the right the div "lockscreenSlider" jerks to the right.

Comment: please post your **CSS** too

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: just added css, I can add a jsfiddle if nessecary

Comment: I've also noticed that I can't replicate the issue in internet explorer. It's a bit difficult to test though because of how I'm sizing things

Comment: maybe this will help: http://jsfiddle.net/mad49p77/

Comment: the movement works perfectly in that jsfiddle but I don't see any large differences that could stop mine from offsetting from the mouse

Comment: I found that removing a tranform: scale(); built around everything, it works perfectly fine. I guess the solution would be to just scale everything with actual positioning

Answer (score 2):

```
transform:scale([anything]);
```

this causes issues with mouse offset